# Min / Max of 3d Matrix using different intervals Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d, intervals, min

I have a 3d matrix A of size MxNxZ. I am searching the minimum for each vector in the Z direction like this.

```
I = min(A(:, :, minInterval : maxInterval), [], 3);
```

This is working.

Now I want to have variable intervals for each vector. I have then two 2d matrices as follow :

```
minIntervals of size MxN
maxIntervals of size MxN
```

I am then trying this :

```
I = min(A(:, :, minIntervals : maxIntervals), [], 3);
```

but it did not work and use only minIntervals(1,1) and maxIntervals(1,1).

Do you have an idea, I don't want to use loop because of the size of the data.

Thank you very much.

Comment: How the third dimension could be a matrix MxN?

Comment: @SivaSrinivasKolukula the third dimension is not a matrix MxN. Using min(A, [], 3) allows to find the minimum of each vector, so the minimum for each A(i,j,:). But I would like to find the minimum only in A(i,j,minInterval:maxInterval). This is working. But how to do when min/maxInterval are changing without using loop? Without using A(i,j,minInterval(i,j):maxInterval(i,j))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set matrix values that are outside the interval to `Inf` and take the min :

In MATLAB r2016b and later:

```
z=reshape(1:size(A,3),1,1,[]);
A(z<minInterval | z>maxInterval)=Inf;
I=min(A,[],3);
```

In pre r2016b:

```
z=reshape(1:size(A,3),1,1,[]);
A(bsxfun(@lt, z, minInterval) | bsxfun(@gt, z,maxInterval))=Inf;
I=min(A,[],3);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it seems to be working. I just have a little problem with the min function. I says that I have too many input arguments. I am using Matlab r2009b, maybe it is because of it?

Comment: @bRiocHe Answer updated.  You can set elements of the array to Inf , instead of `NaN` , so there is no need to omitnan.

Comment: Glad if it can help!